# How can I make a simple CROSSTOOL for choosing a newer GCC?

Tags: gcc, bazel, build-system

Bazel is using my system's version of `gcc` (which points to `gcc-5`).
Instead, I want to use `gcc-7`.

I don't see any way to configure or pass in a different compiler,
which means I must specify it as a `CROSSTOOL`.

I've read all the CROSSTOOL tutorials, but I'm still confused on how to configure this newer version of gcc, because there are so many potential options.

Is there a way to get the default `CROSSTOOL` configuration used?
Because then maybe I could just tweak that to a different compiler.

Otherwise, could anyone point me to a typical standard configuration of using `gcc-7`.
I am able to change my system version of `gcc` to point to `gcc-7`, and that builds correctly, which is why I'm looking for the simplest `CROSSTOOL` configuration that essentially does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the autoconfigured crosstool that is shipped with bazel, you can just set `CC` environment variable to point to the `gcc-7`.

Comment: Oh! I've been using flags like `--cxxopt` for `bazel build`, but I hadn't seen anything for selecting a compiler that way.  Its good to know bazel will pull from environment variables also.  These kinds of things are less hermetic, but that seems like the best option for now until I get a working `CROSSTOOL` file.